# What type of portal was used in Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

Reed Richards (Mr Fantastic) comes to the Illuminati hall using some kind of portal.

What kind of portal it is? Is it similar to the ones used by TVA in Loki series? Does it work on quantum energy for teleportation?

Comment: I think Quantum Energy just [stabilises people who are phasing out of existence due to weird experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characters_of_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe:_M–Z#Ava_Starr_/_Ghost). Surely there's no way it could be used for teleportation as well!

Comment: I don't think this is a spoiler. He was in the trailers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is addressed in the Director's Commentary. Sam Raimi refers to it as a '*teleportation device*' and talks briefly about its inspiration.

> "The detail of the teleportation device he uses to get into the scene is something we took from the comics, that’s Doctor Doom’s '*time door*'.”

> [image]
> <sub><sub>[**Iron Man: Legacy of Doom Vol. 1 #1**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Man:_Legacy_of_Doom_Vol_1_1)</sub></sub>

Answer (score 4):

Currently, we don't know, we have no information on it beyond that very shot clip of Reed using it to arrive at Strange's trial. We don't know how it works or if it really is similar to anything we've seen before. It certainly doesn't act like the portals we've seen before.

Those in *Loki*, the Timedoors, create a physical orange light door shape to step through that remains open until closed. Reed's portal appears to be remote controlled and is a blue light shape. However, it is a square-ish shape that moves from toe to head up the body revealing a bit at a time. So it certainly isn't the exact same technology.

[image: The Variant drags an incapacitated Minuteman through a timedoor] [image: Reed appears at the council using his portal technology, it is halfway up his torso]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.* - Bad quality image for Reed's portal but the best I can get at the moment!</sub>

Of course we should also state that the timedoors allow crossing timelines (multiverses), locations and time. Whereas it would appear that Reed's portal can only move location, that would appear to be a safe assumption thus far anyway. They don't want people crossing universe for fear of an incursion so it's unlikely to have that capability.

That said, the lighting effect caused by Reed's portal has some similarities to the TVA's timedoors. It is also worth noting that in the comics Kang, Nathaniel Richards, is said to be a descendant of Reed Richards. It is highly possible this is the case in the MCU and as both are/were scientists the TVA's (Kang's) portal tech is just a more advanced form of the one Reed uses in MoM.

Comment: In short: “a blue one” or “a square one”. Makes sense that Mr Fantastic’s portal is super-boring, whereas America Chavez’s is all star-shaped and zoomy and cool.